# How to calculate properties of voltage regulation circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, pcb-design, circuit-design, zener

I have a few options of adding voltage regulation to my pcb circuit (the regulation is from 12V to 5V). The options are stataed in the figures below.
My question is:

> How do I calculate the quiescent current and time lag for each of the designs?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: #1 Voltage divider divides the voltage, not regulate it, unless your 12V source is stable. It also can't drive "heavy" load because it has low impedance.

Comment: #2 Zener voltage will be very messy if you use that big R.

Comment: Please don't make your question part of an image. Include it in the text of your post so it can be searched for.

Comment: @ThePhoton, There is no equation editor here so I had no other way to insert equations.(or, is there an equation editor i am not aware of?)

Answer (score 1):

First solution: quiescent current is the current flow thru R1, R2 when there is no load.

```
       I = 12 / 25k = 0.48 mA
```

Second solution: the calculation seems theoretically OK.

> Does this mean the "power consumption" is ok ?

OK for what ? For ultra low power demand ?

What is your requirement?

Comment: Thanks. Basic requirements for pcb. I know nothing about common power consumption, this is why I asked

Answer (score 1):

The resistor voltage divider will provide an output voltage that is a fixed fraction of the input voltage, provided you don't draw any significant current from the output.  Any load you add between output and ground appears as a resistor in parallel with R2, and will cause the output voltage to drop.

With the Zener diode, the output voltage will depend on the Zener voltage, unless the load connected across the Zener draws sufficient current to drop more than 7 volts across R1.  If the load does draw sufficient current to cause more than a 7 volt drop across R1, the output voltage will drop.

Either of your circuits could be used as a voltage reference, but should not be expected to deliver any significant current to a load.  Neither circuit should be considered as a voltage regulator.

Comment: Thanks! One thing I didn't get though. Why is the Zener diode version not considered as voltage regulation? I thought a suitable Zener diode will keep the out voltage around 5V. Am I wrong? I mean, what is the different between voltage regulation to voltage reference? Thanks!

Comment: Well...  The Zener circuit is a simple voltage regulator, only suitable for supplying small currents that don't vary much.  To be useful, R1 would have to be much smaller than 30K, as all the load current has to flow through it, and you also need to keep some current flowing through the Zener diode to maintain regulation.